# ''related'' vs ''relatives''

Tags: vocabulary

I want to  make a sentence about someone to whom I am related ,

İt is generally done as in sentence 1 .

What about sentence 2 , would it be natural?

> 1) We are related

(this sentence is ok)

> 2) We are relatives

(is this sentence natural?)

Comment: They're both fine! What doubts do you have about sentence 2?

Comment: someone told me that it is not idiomatic so I wanted to check whether ıt ıs ok

Comment: It sounds natural to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Ngram Viewer shows that 'we are related' is about 20 times more commonly used than 'we are relatives'. Similarly 'you are related' is about 70 times more common than 'you are relatives', and 'they are related' is about 50 times more common than 'they are relatives'.

'We are relatives' is grammatical, and is used, but is far less common than 'We are related'. I would naturally say 'we are related' rather than 'we are relations'. It might depend on whether I was talking *to* the relative, or *about* the relative.

Answer (score 0):

While it may be understood pretty well, I'd say *'We are related'* is not that common in use.

You are talking about *human relations* and that is where, the use of prepositions *'to'* and *'by'* is encouraged.

[Cambridge describes it:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/related)

> related (adjective; family): *If people are related, they belong to the same family*

The examples follow:

> She claims she is **related to** royalty. 
>   Jim and I are **related by** marriage.

So, if you go by dictionaries, you should have proper word usage.